# Range of values for a Nominal Attribute in Weka

Tags: weka, arff

I have a nominal attribute to be used for Numeric Prediction using Weka. But this **Nominal Attribute** happen to have **957 possible values(1-957)**. Is there any way to specify that in the **ARFF input file**. One obvious way is to write a script to generate **1-957** comma separated entries.

But i was just wondering if there is any workaround provided by WEKA?

Comment: How/Why a nominal is used for numeric prediction, are nominals are ordered ? If they are, isn't it better to use numeric ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know. You could use the following shell command to generate all values.

```
seq -s, 1 957
```

Comment: I was wondering, did this ever solve your problem or did you find another solution?